# Raspberry Pi 4 18.04 64-bit image automatic USB disk resizing

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, raspberrypi, usb-drive, arm64

I have four Raspberry Pi 4s with attached USB 3 disks that I am running as a docker cluster. The disks are automatically detected on boot and mounted as the root volume. However, I would like repartition these disks so I can add ceph support to my cluster. I tried resizing the disks manually, but when they were reconnected to the Pis and rebooted, the partitions were automatically grown to the whole disk again. Where is this configured, can it be disabled, or is there a process to resize the root partitions in place?

Comment: As I suspected, this is managed through cloud-init and is documented as part of the image documentation, but I don't think it's expected to apply Raspberry Pis that much. If I find a solution I will update this answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried GParted or another disk partion editor, Disks maybe.
What kind of disk-array setup. Some live-boot systems use 1 partition with iso-joliet cd format wich partition it into 1 system, locksit and throws tge rest of the free-space overboard?...

Comment: The latter could be it. It's not an issue with partitioning, that worked fine with gparted. It doesn't seem to be on the boot partition on disk, so I assume it must be on the microsd boot partition.